# Degenerate parametric amplifier: quadratures

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-optics

The degenerate parametric amplifier is described by the Hamiltonian:

$H=\hbar \omega a^\dagger a-i\hbar \chi /2 \left[e^{2i\omega t}a^2-e^{-2i\omega t}(a^\dagger)^2\right]$

Where $a$ and $a^\dagger$ as just the operators of creation and anhiquilation and $\chi$ is just a real constant.

If we define the quadratures as:

$X_1=a+a^\dagger \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ; \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ X_2=a-a^\dagger$

How can we calculate the quadratic fluctuations (uncertainties) of these quadratures? In particular, I read that they satisfy the equations:

$(\Delta X_i)^2(t)=e^{(2\chi t)}(\Delta X_i)^2(0)$

I tried applying the Dirac picture with, as we can easily separate:

$H=\underbrace{\hbar \omega a^\dagger a}_{H_0}+\underbrace{-i\hbar \chi /2 \left[e^{2i\omega t}a^2-e^{-2i\omega t}(a^\dagger)^2\right]}_{H_1}$

Where $H_0$ is just the Hamiltonian for the harmonic oscillator (with known solution) and $H_1$ is just a perturbation. This allows to find the equations of motion for $a$ and $a^\dagger$, but I'm not sure how to get the form of $(\Delta X_i)^2 (t)$ shown above.

PD: I haven't studied time-dependent perturbation theory so I'm not sure if it's necessary to solve this problem.

Comment: You second expression for $H$ can't be right as it's not hermitian.  Looks like you're missing a part in $H_1$.

Comment: You're right, I missed a couple of terms when writing. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Commonly, the quadratures are defined as $X_1=(\hat{a}^{\dagger}+\hat{a})/2$ and $X_2=i(\hat{a}^{\dagger}-\hat{a})/2$. You can use the equations of motion for the operators $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ and $\hat{a}$. Solve the differential equations for these, which are not complicated. Then use the quadrature operators.  On page 41 of the paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.3439), there is a process that could help you finish the calculation.